# Error query.skip is not a function when separated from await Order.find({...})

Tags: node.js

I'm working on a project where I'm trying to paginate `orders` in order from the most recent to oldest. Before, I added the pagination I had a `.sort()` that covered this in the frontend, but after adding the pagination it wasn't working properly, so I figured it was best to do this in the backend before any pagination occurred. I'm using `.skip()` and `.limit()` to create my pagination. I'm currently, getting an issue stating `query.skip is not a function`. I've added `console.log(query)` to check what values the array has, and I get a list of all of the `orders` in the correct order. When I first added the pagination I had:`await Order.find({user:req.user._id}).skip(skip).limit(perPage)`,
which didn't give me any errors, but when I separate `.skip()` I keep getting the stated error. I'm unsure why I'm getting this error, and I would really appreciate any help or advice on how to fix this. Thank you!

```
orderRouter.get(
    '/mine',
    isAuth,
    expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
        const page = parseInt(req.query.page) || 1;
        const perPage = parseInt(req.query.limit) || 20;
        const skip = (page - 1) * perPage;
        let userOrders = await Order.find({ user: req.user._id });
        const query = userOrders.sort((a,b) => new Date(b.createdAt) - new Date(a.createdAt));
        const orders = query.skip(skip).limit(perPage)
        res.status(200).send(orders);
    }),
);
```

Additional Note:

```
let userOrders = await Order.find({ user: req.user._id });
const query = userOrders.skip(skip).limit(perPage)
```

Also, gives an error stating `userOrders.skip is not a function`

And if I have:

```
let userOrders = await Order.find({ user: req.user._id }).sort((a,b) => new Date(b.createdAt) - new Date(a.createdAt))
```

I'm getting an error stating: `Invalid sort() argument. Must be a string, object, or array.`

Comment: const skipVar = (page - 1) * perPage;         const orders = query.skip(skipVar).limit(perPage)


Try this. I am guessing this is the issue.

Comment: @subodhkalika Hi, unfortunately, that's still giving me the same error

Comment: try console.log(typeof((query.skip)).) Also console.log(query.skip) to debug

Comment: so   ```console.log(typeof((query.skip())));```, ```console.log(query.skip())```, ```console.log(typeof((query.skip(skipVar))));```, and ```console.log(query.skip(skipVar))``` return nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else is having trouble with this, the issue was that `.sort()` is not a normal javascript `.sort()`. Instead, `.sort()` needs to be written for mongodb, since that is the database that I am using and where my documents are coming from. Due to this, in my case, to `.sort()` for the date a document was created at (`createdAt`) from newest to oldest would be written like this: `.sort({createdAt: -1})`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to not `await` the query as that would get executed and further chaining would happen on the returned object.

Something like below:

```
const userOrdersQuery = Order.find({ user: req.user._id });
const userOrders = await userOrdersQuery.skip(skip).limit(perPage);
```

Comment: Hi, so without await before ```Order.find(...``` I get the schema for Order instead of the arrays for ```orders```, which is  probably because I'm getting my data from  a mongodb database and it didn't have enough time to get the documents. Due to this I end up having an error with ```.sort()```.

Comment: @pelotador.1 Are you using mongoose or native mongodb driver? As mongoose returns a query for .find() https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find